# How to check if array values are empty, in bulk?

Tags: arrays, bash, variables

I want a script bash/sh/ksh which compare a lot of variables, maybe in an array, and tell me if variable is empty or not.

I think something like this, it but doesn't work.

```
ARRAY=(
bash="yes"
cash=""
trash="no"
empty=""
)

for var in "${ARRAY[@]}"; do
if [ "$var" == "$empty" ]
then
echo "$var is empty"
else
echo "$var is not empty"
fi
done
```

I want an output like this

```
bash is not empty
cash is empty...
```

Comment: If you run `declare -p ARRAY`, you'll get a result like `declare -a ARRAY='([0]="bash=yes" [1]="cash=" [2]="trash=no" [3]="empty=")'`, showing that your keys are currently `0`, `1`, `2` and `3`, vs the presumably-intended values of `bash`, `cash`, `trash` and `empty`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're willing to limit your runtime environment to a recent version of bash (or modify the code to support ksh93's equivalent syntax),

```
#!/bin/bash
#      ^^^^ -- specifically, bash 4.0 or newer

declare -A array # associative arrays need to be declared!
array=( [bash]="yes" [cash]="" [trash]="no" [empty]="" )

for idx in "${!array[@]}"; do
  if [[ ${array[$idx]} ]]; then
    echo "$idx is not empty"
  else
    echo "$idx is empty"
  fi
done
```

To iterate over *keys* in an array, as opposed to *values*, the syntax is `"${!array[@]}"`, as opposed to `"${array[@]}"`; if you merely iterate over the values, you don't know the name of the one currently being evaluated.

---

Alternately, let's say we aren't going to use an array at all; another way to set a namespace for variables you intend to be able to treat in a similar manner is by prefixing them:

```
#!/bin/bash

val_bash=yes
val_cash=
val_trash=no
val_empty=

for var in "${!val_@}"; do
  if [[ ${!var} ]]; then
    echo "${var#val_} is not empty"
  else
    echo "${var#val_} is empty"
  fi
done
```

This works (on bash 3.x as well) because `"${!prefix@}"` expands to the list of variable names starting with `prefix`, and `"${!varname}"` expands to the contents of a variable whose name is itself stored in the variable `varname`.

Comment: Maybe you should include a shebang line, as the question mentions "bash/sh/ksh".

Answer (score 2):

Iterate over the array elements, and inside the loop for `read` set `IFS` as `=` to get variable and it's value in two separate variables, then check if the value is empty:

```
for i in "${array[@]}"; do 
    IFS== read var value <<<"$i"
    if [ -z "$value" ]; then
        echo "$var is empty"
    else
        echo "$var is not empty"
    fi
done
```

**Outputs:**

```
bash is not empty
cash is empty
trash is not empty
empty is empty
```

Comment: If the OP's data structure is really immutible, and intended to be exactly what it is in the question, then this is certainly correct. I'm not sure that's the case, though -- they talk about being willing to accept any sh/ksh/bash solution, so surely they're flexible on syntax. If the goal is to choose a syntax that's the Right Tool For The Job, then I'd argue that an associative array is the only sensible choice: Who wants to need to iterate through a numerically-indexed array to find the variable they want?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I second. An associative array is the _right_ data structure here.